# How can I get alternative row color when paginating and sorting a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

I have a demo on the following link:

http://mywebbapp.com/tableSortingDemo.html

When you click on the Status column and start sorting and then click on the pagination arrow to go to page 2 the rows don't alternate color until you click on the Status column again. Is there a script I can write to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though I suggest using a premade table such as [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/%20DataTables).

Here's a small jQuery plugin that could be used if you can trigger it when you paginate:

```
jQuery.fn.stripe = function() {
    $(this).find('tr').removeClass('even odd').filter(':odd').addClass('odd').end().find('tr:even').addClass('even');
}

$('#table').stripe();
```

Then be sure to have some CSS that changes the color:

```
tr.odd { background: #fff }
tr.even { background: #ddd }
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested that plugin -- I use a slightly different one modified for my purposes, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your logic to specify the background colors for the rows is just running in the wrong place.  Without seeing your code, it's impossible to really debug it, though.